# GtkEntry transparent background without making the whole widget transparent?

Tags: c, gtk

I want to just make the background transparent not the whole widget, I know I can make a whole window transparent, but then the cursor fades out too? In essence for gtk_widget_modify_bg I would like to pass a transparent color. I tried using this:

```
GdkColor color;
gkd_color_parse(&color, "#000000000");
gtk_widget_modify_bg ...
```

The color comes out as black, or some random transparent color.

I tried doing this but still no result:

```
static gboolean on_expose(GtkWidget *widget,  GdkEventExpose *event,   gpointer data)
{
  cairo_t *cr;
  cr = gdk_cairo_create(gtk_widget_get_window(widget));
  cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 0, 0, 1, 0.1);
  cairo_destroy(cr);

  return FALSE;
}
```

I guess `gdk_window_shape_combine_mask` might be another direction.

Comment: Are you using Gtk+ 2.x or 3.x ?

Comment: Then you're doing thing the wrong way. With Gtk+-3.x you need to connect to draw signal, not expose, and that draw signal provides you with a cairo_context suitable for drawing.

Comment: Second, and I think this is mainly why noone has answer you. GtkEntry is a complex widget, it has a lot of layers internally, and the text handling isn't simple. So you should look into GtkEntry code inside Gtk+ or rethink your approach. You might want to create your own widget.